# Changing orientation of armature in edit mode without breaking animations

Tags: animation, armature, bones, edit-mode

I imported an armature into blender with animations included. The problem is that the skeleton uses the Y-axis as the up axis, and I need to use the Z-axis.

I have tried rotating it manually in edit mode, but the animations contort

Any help appreciated

Comment: What format of file are you importing? Some formats let you specify Y and Z direction on import (.obj, for example).

Comment: I'm using an add-on to import the model. The extension is .semodel. I wanted to import like that but unfortunately I don't have an option to, hence why I'm trying to just fix after import. The animation is correctly lined up with that axis as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I can do this by just going into object mode, rotating the armature and applying the rotation